# json_decode() - syntax error

Tags: php, json

I want to remove special chars (and found this in a forum):

```
$response = trim(preg_replace("#(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|([\s\t]//.*)|(^//.*)#", '', $response));
```

The same for this

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) {
    $response = str_replace(chr($i), "", $response);
}

$response = str_replace(chr(127), "", $response);

if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($response), 'efbbbf')) {
    $response = substr($response, 3);
}
```

And this for encoding

```
$response = mb_convert_encoding($response, "UTF-8");
echo "\nJSON Response:#$response#\n";
```

At this point `$response` echoes:

```
{"data":{"taxa":[{"placa":"EDY8986","taxas_detran":"141.36","seguro_dpvat":"211.30","ipva":"1945.20","multas":"5048.10","total_debitos":"null"}]},"code":200,"pagination":{"rows":1,"page":1,"pages":0,"hasNext":false,"totalRows":1}}
```

In the end

```
$data = json_decode('"' . $response . '"',true, 512);
echo "\n\nData>\n";
print_r($data);
echo "\nError> "; echo json_last_error_msg();
```

`json_last_error_msg()` prints:

> Syntax Error

I've already validated it in JSONLint and JSON Formatter and it is valid.

Comment: `$data = json_decode($response,true, 512);`

Comment: I can't believe it. Maybe i get crazy. Thanks man, its working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to just littile bit change and it work fine:-**

```
$data = json_decode($response,true, 512);// remove quotes
```

Answer (score 1):

You're killing your JSON with the extra quotes:

```
 $data = json_decode('"' . $response . '"',true, 512);
                      ^-----------------^
```

Assuming your $response is

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

Then you'd be producing/passing

```
"{"foo":"bar"}"
```

which is an outright JSON syntax error:

```
"{"foo":"bar"}"
^--start string
  ^-end string
   ^^^---????
```